# Redux architecture confuse about initial store state

Tags: reactjs, redux

All:

I am pretty new to React and Redux. Currently I want to build a header menu with several menu item in it which look like:

[image]

> Each item can be click and highlighted (just use same color to highlight), the click action is toggling the highlight of that item.

I try to follow the pattern of redux, which saves the state of each item in a store ( this is the first place which confuses me, I am not sure if I should save this **highlight state in component so it is easier for user specify initial highlight state, or in global store so I can sync everywhere** ). But I do not know **how to design the data structure for this**, especially when it allows user to specify item initial state in JSX (such as `<MenuItem highlight={true} />`)

Any example for this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the redux store for a trivial thing like the highlight state of the items. think of it this way. your store is there to store data from the server. the small things that change on the component like a color or a className should be handled in state of the component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {highlighted: 1};
        this.handleHighlightClick = this.handleHighlightClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleHighlightClick(e, val){
        //set state here for your highlight
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({highlighted: val})
    }
    render(){
        // for the sake of this example i'll just show a list of items to render
        let menuItems = [{color: 'red'},{color: 'orange'},{color: 'yellow'},{color: 'white'}];
        return (
            {menuItems.map((data, key) => 
                <MenuItem 
                  data={data} // data is the color object from the list
                  highlighted={key===this.state.highlighted} // the key of which one is highlighted gets stored in local state
                  onClick={(e) => { this.handleHighlightClick(e, key)} } /> // inline function to pass through the key of the exact menu item so that you can save its key to state
            )}
        );
    }
}
```

now this is just a simple example and doesn't cover everything you are trying to do. but its about 90% of what you want to do so I'll let you finish the last 10% :)

Comment: Thanks. My question here is actually related to another question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874685/how-to-build-a-side-toggle-menu-respond-to-header-menu-in-react ) : could you help with?